# How to dynamically show/hide LineString in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm loading a GeoJSON file of aircraft tracks into Leaflet. I'd like to plot current locations as icons and previous 'tracks' as lines. Showing all the tracks gets busy as aircraft increase, so I'd like to be able to toggle them on only when the aircraft is clicked on.

Can/how should I show/hide the LineString separately from the marker dynamically?

I've found suggestions to [set the style transparent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178005) but `.setStyle` applies to the Feature, not the geometry.

[image: Example image]

Summarised GeoJSON:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "reg": "G-CGWP",
        "type": "fixed",
        "model": "website.profile"
      },
      "id": 12,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": [
          {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                -0.319281196282617,
                52.08664390758181
              ],
              [
                -1.076445537370006,
                52.79518475653341
              ],
              [
                -0.098191354875297,
                51.94810149137197
              ],
              [
                -0.940941846648286,
                53.508162348603435
              ]
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -0.940941846648286,
              53.508162348603435
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  ...
  ]
}
```

I do have control of the GeoJSON so can change that.

Answer (score 1):

Since `LineString` collection is represented as `GeometryCollection` you could consider to flatten `GeometryCollection` into `LineString` geometries, (for example via `Turf.js` [`flatten` function](https://turfjs.org/docs/#flatten)):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": [
          {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [-105.00341892242432, 39.75383843460583],
              [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535]
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535],
              [-104.99820470809937, 39.74979664004068]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

into

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-105.00341892242432, 39.75383843460583],
          [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535],
          [-104.99820470809937, 39.74979664004068]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and then apply style per layer

```
layer.on({
   click: function(e) {
      toggleLayerVisibility(e.target);
   }
});
```

where

```
var selectedLayerId = null;
function toggleLayerVisibility(layer) {
    if (selectedLayerId) {
      geojson.resetStyle(layer);
      selectedLayerId = null;
    } else {
      //hide a layer
      layer.setStyle({
        opacity: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.0
      });
      selectedLayerId = layer._leaflet_id;
    }
}
```

Here is an example

```js
var data = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: [
    {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "GeometryCollection",
        geometries: [
          {
            type: "LineString",
            coordinates: [
              [-105.00341892242432, 39.75383843460583],
              [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535]
            ]
          },
          {
            type: "LineString",
            coordinates: [
              [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535],
              [-104.99820470809937, 39.74979664004068]
            ]
          },
          {
            type: "LineString",
            coordinates: [
              [-104.99820470809937, 39.74979664004068],
              [-104.98689651489258, 39.741052354709055]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "MultiPolygon",
        coordinates: [
          [
            [
              [-105.00432014465332, 39.74732195489861],
              [-105.00715255737305, 39.7462000683517],
              [-105.00921249389647, 39.74468219277038],
              [-105.01067161560059, 39.74362625960105],
              [-105.01195907592773, 39.74290029616054],
              [-105.00989913940431, 39.74078835902781],
              [-105.00758171081543, 39.74059036160317],
              [-105.00346183776855, 39.74059036160317],
              [-105.00097274780272, 39.74059036160317],
              [-105.00062942504881, 39.74072235994946],
              [-105.00020027160645, 39.74191033368865],
              [-105.00071525573731, 39.74276830198601],
              [-105.00097274780272, 39.74369225589818],
              [-105.00097274780272, 39.74461619742136],
              [-105.00123023986816, 39.74534214278395],
              [-105.00183105468751, 39.74613407445653],
              [-105.00432014465332, 39.74732195489861]
            ],
            [
              [-105.00361204147337, 39.74354376414072],
              [-105.00301122665405, 39.74278480127163],
              [-105.00221729278564, 39.74316428375108],
              [-105.00283956527711, 39.74390674342741],
              [-105.00361204147337, 39.74354376414072]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [-105.00942707061768, 39.73989736613708],
              [-105.00942707061768, 39.73910536278566],
              [-105.00685214996338, 39.73923736397631],
              [-105.00384807586671, 39.73910536278566],
              [-105.00174522399902, 39.73903936209552],
              [-105.00041484832764, 39.73910536278566],
              [-105.00041484832764, 39.73979836621592],
              [-105.00535011291504, 39.73986436617916],
              [-105.00942707061768, 39.73989736613708]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};




      var map = L.map("map").setView([39.74739, -105], 14);

      L.tileLayer(
        "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw",
        {
          maxZoom: 18,
          attribution:
            'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
          id: "mapbox.light"
        }
      ).addTo(map);

      var data_flatten = turf.flatten(data);

      var geojson = L.geoJSON(data_flatten, {
        style: {
   fillColor: '#1c9099',
            weight: 8
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      }).addTo(map);

      var selectedLayerId = null;
      function toggleLayerVisibility(layer) {
        if (selectedLayerId) {
          geojson.resetStyle(layer);
          selectedLayerId = null;
        } else {
          //hide a layer
          layer.setStyle({
            opacity: 0,
            fillOpacity: 0.0
          });
          selectedLayerId = layer._leaflet_id;
        }
      }

      function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
          click: function(e) {
            toggleLayerVisibility(e.target);
          }
        });
      }
```

```css
 #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
      }
```

```html
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
      crossorigin=""
    />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Turf.js/5.1.5/turf.js"
    ></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a complete example  - not being a JS programmer, this is very useful.